# Ambient Occlusion on Project from View Black bits

Tags: baking, ambient-occlusion

What's causing these weird triangles in black on an Ambient Occlusion bake? I need to use project from view for texturing purposes but it doesn't seem to like this idea much. Is there any way to correct this black shadow triangle issues while keeping my project from view unwrap?

Cheers.

[image]

Comment: Okay then . Please delete the question.

Comment: I'd still like to know what's causing the issue? What causes these black triangle artifacts? Is it triangulation issues? Normals? UV unwrap? Can I not do project from views and have to AO work properly?